# Manifest cannot detected in Quarkus-Omnifaces Extension

Tags: quarkus, omnifaces

I've configured the [PWAResourceHandler](https://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/PWAResourceHandler)  on my Quarkus + Myfaces Application but the manifest.json can't be detected.
I debug the code and see the manifest generating the file. But the manifest is not recognized.

Quarkus: 2.16.3.Final

Quarkus-Omnifaces: 3.14.3

Someone can help ?

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class AppHandlerPWA extends WebAppManifest {

@Override
public String getName() {
    return "AgroV ERP";
}

@Override
public String getShortName() {
    return "AGROV";
}

@Override
public Collection<ImageResource> getIcons() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            ImageResource.of("images/pwa/agrov-icon-144x144.png", Size.SIZE_144),
            ImageResource.of("images/pwa/agrov-icon-180x180.png", Size.SIZE_180),
            ImageResource.of("images/pwa/agrov-icon-180x180.png", Size.SIZE_512)
    );
}

@Override
public String getThemeColor() {
    return "#cc9900";
}

@Override
public String getBackgroundColor() {
    return "#ffffff";
}

@Override
public Display getDisplay() {
    return Display.STANDALONE;
}

@Override
public Collection<Category> getCategories() {
    return Arrays.asList(Category.BUSINESS, Category.FINANCE);
}

@Override
public String getOfflineViewId() {
    return "/webapp/public/offline.html";
}

@Override
public Collection<String> getCacheableViewIds() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            "/webapp/public/login.xhtml"
    );
}

@Override
public Collection<RelatedApplication> getRelatedApplications() {
    return Arrays.asList(
            RelatedApplication.of(Platform.PLAY, "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.app1", "com.example.app1"),
            RelatedApplication.of(Platform.ITUNES, "https://itunes.apple.com/app/example-app1/id123456789")
    );
}
```

}